# CSS for the sidebar affects the upper menu dropdowns

Tags: css

We created a specific right sidebar on some of our pages with items that are on a list. I assigned a class to the `ul` ("sexsidebar") and assigned CSS commands so that the `li` elements would behave differently when hovered upon.

So here's a sample of the HTML code for what's on the sidebar:

```
<ul class="sexsidebar">
<li><a href="/firstURL">Rape</a></li>
<li><a href="/secondURL">Indecent Assault</a></li>
<li><a href="/thirdURL">Child Pornography</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then for the CSS:

```
ul.sexsidebar li
     {background: #F5F5F5;
      margin: 5px;}

ul.sexsidebar li a
     {display: block;}

ul.sexsidebar li:hover, li:hover a
     {background: #57AC68;
      color: #FFFFFF !important;}
```

This actually worked. But for some unknown reason, it affected the look of the dropdowns of the upper menus of "all" of our pages (also in `li`). This I really don't get since the sidebar was assigned a specific class after all (`ul class="sexsidebar"`). So naturally any CSS command pointing to it should be affecting only that class. But why are the upper menu dropdowns affected?

You can view a sample page [here](http://www.criminal-lawyers.com.au/offences/rape). I have however removed the CSS commands for the sidebar (the part with a list of sexual offences) since they're messing up with the upper menu dropdowns. You will see the menus on the upper portion of the page with a green background and the dropdown when you hover on some of the menus.

Hope somebody can explain why a CSS command to the `class="sexsidebar"` affects the upper menu dropdowns. Will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: if you want some extra advice on the other code, you should post the other code as well. There is no way to know how this specific ul affects any other element since we cannot see any other parenting elements, or any other code at all..

Comment: @ZombieChowder will keep this in mind during future questions. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the second part of this selector:

```
ul.sexsidebar li:hover, li:hover a
```

that selects `li:hover a` , i.e. every link in any list item on the whole page.

Change it to this:

```
ul.sexsidebar li:hover, ul.sexsidebar li:hover a
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  I could ask though why even have the "ul.sexsidebar li:hover" it does not seem to add any benefit in this example.

Comment: @orangeh0g true - that one is unnecessary

Comment: I actually tried doing just `ul.sexsidebar li:hover a`. But if I remember it right, it had the effect wherein only the background of `a` element changes, instead of the entire `li`. I had to do both: `li:hover a` for the change in font color and `li:hover` for the change in background.

Comment: Sandy, not meaning to drag this on but since the Anchor tag is display block and the LI container is only as big as the content it holds...in this case the block level Anchor tag then if you supplied a back ground for the LI and the Anchor then the Anchor background would totally hide any background applied to LI.  The only way you would see LI background is if there was padding applied to LI or the Anchor was display inline or inline-block. The reason this is important is lots of stray selectors get added to CSS and this over time causes bloat.

Comment: @orangeh0g not sure I get what you mean. Like I said, I had to do `li:hover a` so I can change the font color when hovered upon. But this alone cannot deal with the background because background of `a` is different from background of `li`. So I had to do `li:hover` to change background of entire `li` when hovered upon. This, too, cannot deal with a change in font color because the texts are in `a` and not in `li` (right?). So I had to do both: `li:hover a` for the texts, and `li:hover` for the background. By the way it's ok to drag this on in the quest for CSS knowledge, lol